# Export/Import bookmarks from Gigolo

Tags: 18.04, gigolo

Is there way to export bookmarks from the tool `gigolo`? I did not find a way in the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bookmarks file can be find at:

```
$HOME/.config/gigolo/bookmarks
```

To have them exported you can just copy the file wherever you want it

```
cp $HOME/.config/gigolo/bookmarks $HOME/bookmarks.bk
```

To import it just move it to the same path:

```
cp $HOME/bookmarks.bk $HOME/.config/gigolo/bookmarks
```

And as you should know the existing bookmarks will be removed.